# Is it possible to render DirectX application without actually showing?

Tags: windows, directx, gpu

I’m going to run the DirectX application on a host machine without actually showing output on the screen. Am i able to connect another monitor and launch game on it, while my default monitor shows different stuff?

I think it could be possible to emulate a monitor, so it's enough to read front buffer using GDI or DirectX to get raw gpu’s output. Am I right? If so, can you tell me how I may implement this, please?

Comment: It's a little unclear from your question exactly what you're asking. It's straightforward in DirectX to render to an off-screen render target and not display it on the monitor. It's also fairly straightforward to handle multiple displays and have your app render to any screen(s) you choose. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm talking about third-party applications, so I haven't source code. Is it straightforward to run the application in the background and capture the GPU-rendered output?

Comment: There is software like FRAPS http://www.fraps.com/ that can capture the rendered output from arbitrary DirectX applications. I'm not sure how FRAPS works but I'd guess it is using DLL injection to intercept D3D calls and redirect rendering to its own buffers.

Comment: @mattnewport Thank’s for your reply, but it doesn’t solve my problem. It requires actual showing game on the real screen.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: 1) I launch the app
2) I put it in the background but still want to capture whats going on in present